# Can I use a past and a future tense verb in the same sentence, connected with an "if"?

Tags: tense

The sentence in question is: " I will talk to you later in the evening, if I WOKE up." I believe that it should be "if I wake up", but the speaker said that this falls under an exception.

Comment: More details please.  What "exception"?

Answer (score 2):

This sentence does not sound fluent. Most likely is a simple non-past condition, indicating that this future event is possible:

> I will talk to you later, if I wake up.

(I will sleep; I may wake up; If so, then I will talk to you)

To speak of a future that will not happen

> I would talk to you if I woke up

(I won't talk to you because I will not wake up.)

or a hypothesis, speaking of an event in the past that didn't happen

> I would have talked to you, if I'd woken up.

(I didn't wake up, so I didn't talk to you)

These are sometimes called type 1, 2 and 3 conditionals.